# Site's background causing strange effect on question title

Tags: discussion, design, questions

I've opened [this question](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/39880/is-a-police-officer-18x-more-likely-to-be-killed-by-a-black-male-than-an-unarmed), and I noticed a strange effect on the last two words of the title:

[image]

At first I thought about a rendering glitch, but then I noticed the other marks and realized (at least I think) it's because of the page's background, which has a feature overlapping strangely with the title. It happens with all questions with long titles.

Is it supposed to behave like that? I found it distracting, especially since I didn't know what it was at first.